# Publish iOS with iTunes connect invitation

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am facing to a problem, I received an invitation from a client, an iTunes connect invitation. This invitation allow me to manage an application for him.
I have developed an iOS app, now I would like to publish this app to the Client's account. 
How can I do that ?

I am able to connect to my iTunes connect account, manage my applications, and with this invitation, manage my client's apps. But from Xcode, how to publish the application ? I spent a couple of hours trying to find a way to do it, but nothing...

Thank you very much if you can help me on this one.

Comment: As a start, you will either need to transfer the App ID to the client's account, or create a new App ID and update it in the app.

Comment: Yes, this part is already done.

Comment: In Xcode menu you should choose product -> archive and ready to send

Comment: @Sqrt make sure that he also added you on the developer center. You'll need his teams certificate to sign the app. Here's the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html

Comment: Hum, maybe that the problem. I am going to look into this on Friday and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Did you change the team on the Target->General tab?

Comment: I can't change the Team, it's only mine. But if he invited me, do I have the privileges with my Team profile to publish the app? We have the same App ID, but when I look in my certificates, I don't have the app ID in it. I am going to ask him tomorrow.